# When working with unit vectors, do we consider the scallor part?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I want to know for perhaps computing dot products etc, that if Im just told the angle between to unit vectors...say pi/6, how would I find the dot product of these two vectors?

Comment: What do you know about dot products and vectors? What do you know about unit vectors?

Comment: And what on earth is a "scallor"?

Answer (score 0):

The scalar product of two unit vectors $u, v$ ($\Vert u \Vert =  \Vert v \Vert = 1$) with a given angle $\theta$ is $$\langle u, v \rangle = \cos \theta$$

since the scalar product is given by

$$\langle a, b \rangle = \Vert a \Vert \Vert b \Vert \cos \theta$$